# Ionic Storage Undefined for Array Of Objects

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic3

I am struggling to get an array of object I have retrieved from my Parse Server but no success.

I am building the app with Ionic 3 and Ionic Storage. It seems that I got a promise instead of value but I have tried everything to fix it.

My search.ts file:

```
import { Data } from './../../services/data';
import { localData } from './../../services/local';
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { Parse } from 'parse';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import {User} from '../../models/User';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/debounceTime';
import {FormControl} from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
selector: 'page-search',
templateUrl: 'search.html',

})

export class SearchPage {
currentUser = Parse.User.current();
query1 = new Parse.Query('Friends');
friendQuery = new Parse.Query('Friends');
query = new Parse.Query(Parse.User);
tmp: any =[];
users: any= [];
user: any =[];  

initializeItems() {
this.users = this.dataService.tmpusers;

}

retrieveUsers(){
if (this.currentUser= Parse.User.current()) {
  Parse.Cloud.run('UserQuery').then(
  res => {
    console.log('user query')
    this.tmp = res;
    console.log(this.tmp);
    this.dataService.setUsers2(this.tmp);
    this.users = this.dataService.tmpusers;
    console.log(this.users);

  }
  )
  }
  }

  retrieveFriends(){
  if (this.currentUser= Parse.User.current()) {
  Parse.Cloud.run('FriendsQuery', {currentuser: 'fEjQgAPvDO'}).then(
  res => {
    console.log(res)
    }
  )
  }     
  }

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, private localdata: localData, 
  private dataService: Data) {
  this.searchControl = new FormControl;

  }

  showUsers: any = false;
  searchControl: FormControl;
  searchTerm: string = '';
  searching: any = false;

  filterusers(searchTerm){ 
    return this.users.filter((user) => {
        return user.username.toLowerCase().indexOf(searchTerm.toLowerCase()) 
   > -1;
    });    
  }

  ionViewDidLoad() {
  this.retrieveFriends();
  this.retrieveUsers();
  this.setFilteredItems();
  this.searchControl.valueChanges.debounceTime(700).subscribe(search => {
  this.searching = false;
  this.setFilteredItems();
   });
  }

  onSearchInput(){
  this.searching = true;
  }

  setFilteredItems() {
  this.initializeItems();
  this.users = this.filterusers(this.searchTerm);
  }  

  onCancel(ev: any) {
  this.initializeItems();
  }
  }
```

and my Data.ts file:

```
import { Storage } from '@ionic/storage';
import { Injectable, Component } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class Data {

tmpusers = this.getUsers2();

constructor(public storage: Storage){

}

getUsers2() {
this.storage.get('users');
}

setUsers2(users){
this.storage.set('users', users);
}

}
```

When I am trying to run this, the first console log returns me the array of the users but the second one, which I need is undefined.

What can I do?

I am sorry for the large part of code

Thank you very much

latest code

```
import { Data } from './../../services/data';
import { localData } from './../../services/local';
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { Parse } from 'parse';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import {User} from '../../models/User';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/debounceTime';
import {FormControl} from '@angular/forms';



@Component({
  selector: 'page-search',
  templateUrl: 'search.html',

})

export class SearchPage {
  currentUser = Parse.User.current();
  query1 = new Parse.Query('Friends');
  friendQuery = new Parse.Query('Friends');
  query = new Parse.Query(Parse.User);
  tmp: any =[];
  users: any= [];
  user: any =[];  



initializeItems() {

    this.users = this.dataService.newusers;
    }

retrieveUsers(){
  if (this.currentUser= Parse.User.current()) {
    Parse.Cloud.run('UserQuery').then(
    res => {
      console.log('user query')
      this.tmp = res;
      console.log(this.tmp);
      this.dataService.setUsers2(this.tmp).then(()=>{
          this.dataService.getUsers2().then((val)=>{
           this.users = val;
            console.log(this.users);
        });

       });
     });
    }
   }




retrieveFriends(){
    if (this.currentUser= Parse.User.current()) {
      Parse.Cloud.run('FriendsQuery', {currentuser: 'fEjQgAPvDO'}).then(
      res => {
        console.log(res)
        }
      )
    }
   }

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, private localdata: localData, private dataService: Data) {
      this.searchControl = new FormControl;
  }

  showUsers: any = false;
  searchControl: FormControl;
  searchTerm: string = '';
  searching: any = false;

  filterusers(searchTerm){ 
        return this.users.filter((user) => {
            return user.username.toLowerCase().indexOf(searchTerm.toLowerCase()) > -1;
        });    
     }

  ionViewDidLoad() {
    this.retrieveFriends();
    this.retrieveUsers();
    this.setFilteredItems();
    this.searchControl.valueChanges.debounceTime(700).subscribe(search => {
      this.searching = false;
      this.setFilteredItems();
       });
  }

  onSearchInput(){
    this.searching = true;
    //this code is to hide users until input is triggered
    //if (this.searchTerm.length >=1)
   // return this.showUsers= true;
   // else {
   //   return this.showUsers = false;
   // }
    //end of code
  }

  setFilteredItems() {
    this.initializeItems();
    this.users = this.filterusers(this.searchTerm);
  }  

  onCancel(ev: any) {
    this.initializeItems();
  }

  //searchfriends() {
   // this.friendQuery = new Parse.Query.or(this.query1.equalTo('fromUser',Parse.User.current()),this.query1.equalTo('toUser',Parse.User.current()));
    //let users = this.query.find();
    //return this.users;
  //}
}
```

and the data.ts

```
import { Storage } from '@ionic/storage';
import { Injectable, Component } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class Data {
newusers = [];

    tmpusers = this.getUsers2();

  constructor(public storage: Storage){
    }

    getUsers2(): Promise<any> {
      return this.storage.get('users');
    }  

 setUsers2(users): Promise<any> {
  return this.storage.set('users', users);
}

}
```

old code working

```
import { Data } from './../../services/data';
import { localData } from './../../services/local';
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { Parse } from 'parse';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import {User} from '../../models/User';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/debounceTime';
import {FormControl} from '@angular/forms';



@Component({
  selector: 'page-search',
  templateUrl: 'search.html',

})

export class SearchPage {
  currentUser = Parse.User.current();
  query1 = new Parse.Query('Friends');
  friendQuery = new Parse.Query('Friends');
  query = new Parse.Query(Parse.User);
  tmp: any =[];
  users: any= [];
  user: any =[];  

  initializeItems() {
   this.users = this.localdata.tmpusers;

    }


   retrieveUsers(){
   if (this.currentUser= Parse.User.current()) {
    Parse.Cloud.run('UserQuery').then(
   res => {
   console.log('user query')
   this.tmp = res;
   console.log(this.tmp);
   this.localdata.setUsers(this.tmp);
   this.users = this.localdata.tmpusers;
   console.log(this.users);

  });
  }
  }

 retrieveFriends(){
    if (this.currentUser= Parse.User.current()) {
      Parse.Cloud.run('FriendsQuery', {currentuser: 'fEjQgAPvDO'}).then(
      res => {
        console.log(res)
        }
      )
    }
   }

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, private localdata: localData, private dataService: Data) {
      this.searchControl = new FormControl;
  }

  showUsers: any = false;
  searchControl: FormControl;
  searchTerm: string = '';
  searching: any = false;

  filterusers(searchTerm){ 
        return this.users.filter((user) => {
            return user.username.toLowerCase().indexOf(searchTerm.toLowerCase()) > -1;
        });    
     }

  ionViewDidLoad() {
    this.retrieveFriends();
    this.retrieveUsers();
    this.setFilteredItems();
    this.searchControl.valueChanges.debounceTime(700).subscribe(search => {
      this.searching = false;
      this.setFilteredItems();
       });
  }

  onSearchInput(){
    this.searching = true;
    //this code is to hide users until input is triggered
    //if (this.searchTerm.length >=1)
   // return this.showUsers= true;
   // else {
   //   return this.showUsers = false;
   // }
    //end of code
  }

  setFilteredItems() {
    this.initializeItems();
    this.users = this.filterusers(this.searchTerm);
  }  

  onCancel(ev: any) {
    this.initializeItems();
  }

  //searchfriends() {
   // this.friendQuery = new Parse.Query.or(this.query1.equalTo('fromUser',Parse.User.current()),this.query1.equalTo('toUser',Parse.User.current()));
    //let users = this.query.find();
    //return this.users;
  //}
}
```

and the local.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

export class localData {

    setUsers (users){
        window.localStorage.users_data = JSON.stringify(users);
    }
    getUsers(){
       return JSON.parse(window.localStorage.users_data || '[]');
    }

    tmpusers = this.getUsers();
    constructor(){
        this.tmpusers.sort(function(a, b) {
            var nameA = a.username.toUpperCase(); // ignore upper and lowercase
            var nameB = b.username.toUpperCase(); // ignore upper and lowercase
            if (nameA < nameB) {
              return -1;
            }
            if (nameA > nameB) {
              return 1;
            }

            return 0;
          });
    }  

}
```

Comment: What did you mean `second one`?

Comment: console.log(this.users);

Answer (score 0):

You cannot access that value like that since those are `Async` operations.You can try as shown below.

*data.ts*

```
getUsers2(): Promise<any> {
  retrun this.storage.get('users');
}

setUsers2(users): Promise<any> {
   return this.storage.set('users', users);
}
```

*search.ts*

```
retrieveUsers(){
if (this.currentUser= Parse.User.current()) {
  Parse.Cloud.run('UserQuery').then(
  res => {
    console.log('user query')
    this.tmp = res;
    console.log(this.tmp);
    this.dataService.setUsers2(this.tmp).then(()=>{
        this.dataService.getUsers2().then((val)=>{
         this.users = val;
          console.log(this.users);
      });

     });
   });
  }
 }
```

Comment: hhmm nice appoach. but i have this error: Typescript Error
Property 'then' does not exist on type 'void'.

Comment: You need to change the methods return type as I mentioned above. Did you do?

Comment: I didnt implement the:  tmpusers = this.getUsers2(); now, there is no error but the list is empty

Comment: Try my way and see that. See the value return from the server and also Storage.

Comment: I implemented exactly what you sent. It seems that it cannot access the property username of the table, so that`s why the empty array. In search.html i have the *ngfor loop and {{user.username}} what i send in image is the console.log. It should return all the columns of the class, but it retruns only the Id

Comment: Can you put your `latest code` under the separate section on your question?

Comment: I cannot see any issue in the `code`. Can you debug and check whether the values coming from the server is right? What is the value of here `console.log(this.users);`?

Comment: yes, in parse server i can see all the columns of the class executed. but here, the console.log(this.users); returns only the column of id

Comment: What is the value of this `this.tmp = res;`?

Comment: here you are [link] (https://imgur.com/a/lajHY) it returns the class of user but also with only id

Comment: Then the problem is there(server code).You need to give a solution for that.Your above question is sorted out now.

Comment: I don't think so..using localstorage with json.stringify and json.parse everything was workin perfect. And it was too much faster..But is this the appropriate storage?

Comment: I'm afraid about your problem solving skills.If something is coming wrong from the server then how can you blame for the Local storage.It stores what came from the server (i.e. this value :`this.tmp = res;` )

Comment: I don't blacem localstorage, i blame ionic storage :) take a look at the question i will edit it with the old code that was working

Comment: It is Localstorage when you use it in the browser. See this `When running in the web or as a Progressive Web App, Storage will attempt to use IndexedDB, WebSQL, and localstorage, in that order.`. Read the doc: http://ionicframework.com/docs/storage/

Comment: ok, i have posted the old code. it was working with localstorage like this [link] (https://imgur.com/a/V2sJ5)

Comment: OK. It is the issue of data formatting which is coming from the server. You need to use  `this.tmp = JSON.stringify(res);` before strong it into the Storage. Try that.

Comment: I tried but i had issue again..i give up..this is the git if you have any idea.. [link](https://github.com/giorgionasis/storage/)

Comment: Will it run on my local PC? Do I need to have permissions for Pass server?

Comment: yes Sampath. The app Id is and ServerUrl is in the files configured.Thank You!